# Comparing two directory recursively, copy content of directory to third directory using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have two directories say A and B. 
I want to compare directory B with A.
Directory A and directory B have many common directories(contains is same) and file.
If file is not present in directory A then copy file to directory C by maintaining directory structure.

e.g. If in Directory A following relative path not is not exist.

```
B/hellboy/MyScripts/dir1/
```

I want to copy this path and descendant files and directory to directory C.

I  tried a lot with the diff command. But I think it is not possible. Please help me to get out of this.

Comment: can u please explain i am new to shell scripting

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) (a relative of [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)), it might provide what you want out of the box.

Comment: i want write script and both source and destination directory in same computer

Answer (score 0):

Does the following script snippet come close to what you are looking for?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Setup for testing:
# mkdir -p A/l1-{1,2,3}/l2-{4,5,6}
# mkdir -p B/l1-{2,3,4,5}/l2-{1,2,3,4}
# touch B/l1-{3,4,5}/l2-{2,3,4}/file-${RANDOM}
# touch {A,B}/l1-2/l2-4/never_goes_to_C

while read f d _; do 
  if [ -e "A/$f" ]; then 
    echo "---> FOUND: A/$f"
  else
    echo "---> NOT FOUND: A/$f, moving to C"
    mkdir -p "C/$d" && cp -a "B/$f" "C/$d"
  fi;
done < <(cd B; find . -printf "%p %h\n")
```